# Simulate and optimize a scheduler job to drain data from a data center

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, scheduling

I have an assignment to simulate a problem which we currently have and that is draining data out of old hard drives. Imagine we have 5 hard disks H1 ... H5. Each has a specific capacity Ci and the remaining space Ri. And, we don't want disks to reach to their full capacity, so we need to come up with a scheduler job which frequently drains data out of a disk and relocates it in some other disks. Now the problem is that this draining process impacts the workflow of our system. The performance of the system can be measured by some metrics lets say M1 and M2. Now, how do I design a draining scheduler which tells me when and how much data should be relocated out of a which disk such that it minimizes the impact on M1 and M2?
I use SimPy to simulate this system in python.

Answer (score 0):

For any realistic and practical scenario; the performance metrics (M1 and M2) will have nothing to do with CPU time or (CPU) scheduling whatsoever. All modern (and most "not modern") disk controllers use DMA/bus mastering to transfer data to/from disk themselves (without using any CPU time to do the transfer) so M1 and M2 will (primarily) depend on disk IO bandwidth and not CPU time.

The device driver for the disk controller should/will support some kind of IO priorities; allowing "when disk controller has nothing more important to do (no higher priority transfers), disk controller driver asks disk controller to transfer data to drain the disk (as pre-arranged by file system layer)". In other words "drain disks when disk is idle" can be achieved merely by using a low IO priority.

However; this alone does not work, and the "only drain when (disk) is idle" idea is fundamentally flawed. The problem is that if the disk is pounded for a long time it can still become full (because the disk controller continually had higher priority work to do), leading to a "no free disk space" critical condition (likely failure). The solution is to make the IO priority of draining depend on how full the disk is. If there's enough remaining space on the disk (more than some threshold), then "IO priority of draining" is the lowest priority (so that it doesn't ruin the performance of normal disk IO); and if there's less free disk space the IO priority of draining is proportional, until you reach "IO priority of draining is highest possible priority because there is no free disk space" (sacrificing performance of normal disk IO to prevent a "no free space at all" critical condition as you approach this extreme). Basically, maybe something like "`if(Ri >= threshold) { draining_IO_priority = (1.0 - threshold / Ri) * (max_IO_priority - min_IO_priority) + min_IO_priority; } else { draining_IO_priority = min_IO_priority; }`"

Also note that the file system layer (and the disk controller driver and almost everything else except some old user-space APIs) is primarily event driven. When the file system receives a request that would cause disk space to be allocated (e.g. resulting from a process doing a "`write()`") it responds to the event by deciding if it needs to send a "drain request" to disk controller (in addition to allocating some disk space) or deciding if a previous request needs an IO priority boost; when file system receives a "drain request completed" reply event from disk controller it decides if it needs to send another drain request to disk controller; etc. With this in mind, the file system layer should use a "high CPU scheduler" priority to respond to events quickly (but that has nothing to do with disk IO priorities).

Finally; yes there is an "IO scheduler" (e.g. possibly built into the disk controller's driver); but this is hopefully an extremely trivial "when one transfer completes, find the highest priority pending transfer and do that next" algorithm that doesn't require much thought or complexity. However, for some cases it depends on the device (e.g. for old "rotating mechanical disk" hard drives an attempt to reduce/optimize seek times may be involved).

I guess what I'm trying to say is that, for a well designed system, a "draining scheduler" should not exist at all.